# How to create a separate Loop for custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm building a guitar lessons site and I have a question about Custom Post Types. I am creating a "Lessons" page which will be my main blog / loop. I also wanted to create a custom post type for "Arrangements" which will be just video / songs I arrange and play.

I'm using CPT UI for the custom post type called "Arrangements" and I'm trying to figure out how to create separate loops - Lessons = main post type, Arrangements = custom post type.

I have a arrangements.php template that has a loop like so:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => array('post', 'arrangements'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$new_post_loop = new WP_Query($args);

if ($new_post_loop->have_posts()) :

    while ($new_post_loop->have_posts()) :

        $new_post_loop->the_post();

        get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'blog');

    endwhile;

    the_posts_navigation();

else :

    get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none');

endif;
?>
```

However, it's pulling in all of my Lessons as well as the custom post type. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the default WordPress `posts`  as "Lessons"?

Comment: Yes - sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify this, but if your `lessons` are being pulled in along with your `arrangements` then you must be using default WordPress `posts` for the Lessons...  assuming that, here's what's happening in your code.

On the second line when you're setting your query arguments (`$args`) you specify that you want BOTH the `posts` post type and your custom `arrangements` post type.  So you get both.

Simple fix though, just use this for your `$args`.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'arrangements,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
```

You *could* still leave it as an array though, no harm...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => array('arrangements'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
```

Give that a try and see if you get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed it.

Comment: Glad to help.  :-)